# Json returned with space

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to check if In the json there is a certain property. Actually I can do it in the following way:

```
var container = (JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
var x = container.ToString(Formatting.None);
var message = container["text"];
```

now the variable `responseText` is returned as:

```
{[
{
    "trace": {
      "details": {
        "data": "[29-02-2016 17:37:32.931751]",
        "type": "[info]",
        "text": "[Done.]"
      },
      "context": {
        "context": [
          [
            {
              "ID": "John Dillinger"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]}
```

in the `x` variable I have removed the space and the final result is:

```
"[{\"trace\":{\"details\":{\"data\":\"[29-02-2016 17:37:32.931751]\",\"type\":\"[info]\",\"text\":\"[Done.]\"},\"context\":{\"context\":[[{\"ID\":\"John Dillinger\"}]]}}}]"
```

Now if the key isn't found I get `null`:

```
if (message == null)
{
      return responseText; 
}
```

the problem is that I perform the condition on the `message` variable that check if in the `container` (not formatted) there is the property, the problem is that I get  this exception:

> {"Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: \"text\". Int32 array index expected."}

but if I replace `container` with the second json with the slash all working good. Now my problem is that I can't execute `var message= x["text"];` 'cause `x` is a string. So how I can remove the space in the json and check if contain the `text` key?

Comment: Why not just read it from `container`?  I don't understand why you need to remove all the whitespace before reading that property?

Comment: @JamesThorpe 'cause if I read from container I get: `{"Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: \"text\". Int32 array index expected."}` in particular seems that the casting `JContainer` add space that broken the json. Instead if I relace with a sample variable that contains the json I get the achieve result but I need to get it from the variable that contains the request.

Comment: Do you realize you're really doing nothing? x is where you're removing the spaces but you don't use it for anything...

Comment: Also a cast can't add an space, an object is an object, casting only changes how you treat it in your code, the object remains the same...

Comment: @Gusman well I know this, but code fall in exception when the `text` property isn't found.

Comment: That's because it's a JArray, and then it can't access to the properties, you need to access an element on it: container[0]["trace"]["detailsi"]["text"]

Comment: @Gusman your answer is correct but, what's happean if I have a different json? If I have a json like this: `{
     "status": true,
     "Text": "Example"
}` I will get the same exception.. So this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Then you're creating an inconsistent model, if you're returning different models from the same resource, then do all inherit a base structure, then you can check safely which type to deserialize as the response message will have a common part indicating which model to use.

Comment: There is no other way to check if the content exists in the current json or not? I should have even the same json structure? Seems bad

Comment: @Gusman the problem should be solved I guess iterating over container

Comment: What seems bad is to have different responses in a same resource with the same response code

Comment: @Gusman I don't think, in your point of view I should create a redundant code in each class that need to get an `HttpRequest`. This code is part of the core of the request, if no json data is returned but only the json above (see comment) other class not must reiceve nothing.

Comment: Do you have a [different account/name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35701020/1070452) for each language tag?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you removed the space, you also changed the order of the first brackets In the first example your first brackets are `{[`, in the second they are `[{`

In json, the ordering makes a difference. `{}` means object and `[]` means array.
`[{"data":"value"}]` is legal because you are saying that you have an array of an object. `{["value"]}` is not legal because your object does not have a name for the array. The legal version would be `{ "data":["value"] }`

[Here](http://jsonlint.com/) is a handy web tool to verify your JSON syntax

Comment: It's not a problem of syntax, 'cause in other class I can deserialize the json correctly. It's the problem of the deserialization that 'cause the exception.

Comment: I pasted his JSON into JSONLint and it came back as valid?

Comment: @Sandokan right, my point being his suggestion that JSONLint would have helped is incorrect. JSONLint is a great tool, but it's not giving you any information here.

Comment: I know, but the main problem is find a property that in some case missing in the json 'cause I pass different json each time.

Comment: The JSON before the spaces are removed is not valid. After the space removal it is valid because the brackets are switched to be correct.

Comment: @spectacularbob you're right. But here the problem is on the object container. Need to find a property in different json structure.